# Subquery with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, recurrence

I have two tables:

**__Table R_____**

```
ID.....CustID....DATE
1......1.........2000-01-01
2......2.........2000-01-02
3......2.........2000-01-03
4......2.........2000-02-22
5......1.........2000-03-23
```

**__Table Customers______**

```
ID....NAME
1.....Lucas
2.....Michael
```

Please, how could I do a SELECT which returns the **last** DATE from each customer's NAME? (this way):

```
Lucas......2000-03-23
Michael....2000-02-22
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, `MAX()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select c.name,  max(r.date) 
from table_customers c
join table_r r on r.custid = c.id
group by c.id,  c.name;
```

Comment: It works too! Thank you. However, why GROUP BY c.name? Isn't enough with grouping by c.id?

Comment: I don't know your `sql_mode` value.  So If you have set it to `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` then it would throw an error if you are grouping by only c.id. If not then it would return any value of `name` from that group.

Answer (score 0):

The select you need, using [MAX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html) will return the lastest date:

```
SELECT customer.name, MAX(r.date)
```

The [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) from the two tables:

```
FROM r INNER JOIN customer ON r.custid = customer.id
```

But, if you need the lastest date of each Customer, you need to [group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) it:

```
GROUP BY r.custid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.name, r.date 
from table_customers c 
join table_r r on r.custid = c.id 
ORDER BY r.date DESC 
LIMIT 2 ;
```